# Iframe, MasterPage C#

Tags: c#, html, iframe, master-pages

I am creating a web application C# asp.net . I have a simple menu but I do no know if using 
iframes to show different options according to the menu is better than using a masterpage.

I am pretty new at this. I read that iframes are not being used anymore.

Is there any other option that I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I wouldn't use iframes in that context. At one point they were used to give the impression of something akin to Ajax, but you'll really only find them used these days for embedding videos, audio, etc. from other sites (e.g. YouTube, Soundcloud). Master pages should suffice - you'll have a master page with the menu itself, and any menu selection will load an entirely different page, albeit with the same menu provided by the master page. If you're looking to provide navigation without an entire page refresh, then you're getting into the realm of SPAs (single page applications), which will require the use of Ajax.